# ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Tags: plsql

It says procedure created with compilation errors.

```
    `create or replace procedure fact(n in number, r out number);
    i number:=n
    f number:=1;
    begin
    while(i>1) loop
    f:=f*1;
    i=i-1;
    r=f;
    end fact;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few syntax errors; compare your code with mine, find the differences:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fact (n IN NUMBER, r OUT NUMBER)
  2  AS
  3     I   NUMBER := n;
  4     f   NUMBER := 1;
  5  BEGIN
  6     WHILE (i > 1)
  7     LOOP
  8        f := f * i;
  9        i := i - 1;
 10     END LOOP;
 11
 12     r := f;
 13  END fact;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_out   NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4     fact (4, l_out);
  5     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_out);
  6  END;
  7  /
24

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Though, why did you choose to create a procedure? A function might be more appropriate in this case:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_fact (n IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     i   NUMBER := n;
  5     f   NUMBER := 1;
  6  BEGIN
  7     WHILE (i > 1)
  8     LOOP
  9        f := f * i;
 10        i := i - 1;
 11     END LOOP;
 12
 13     RETURN f;
 14  END;
 15  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT f_fact (4) FROM DUAL;

 F_FACT(4)
----------
        24

SQL>
```